# Are the interior of all 2-manifolds, flat?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to understand curvature in 3-manifold. It seems to me that any 3-manifold which can be written as a boundary of some 2-manifold embedded into $\mathbb{R^3}$  is flat. For instance, suppose we have a sphere, whil the surface itself is curved, I think the interior volume is flat and we can experience no curvature (Riemann curvature tensor is vanishing).

Is the above result generally true?

Comment: Surely it would have to be? The interior of any smooth 2 manifold embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ would just be an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$ which is flat?

Comment: I thought there would be issues as the points approach the boundary. I'm just beginning to learn this material and checking if my intuition is correct. It is clear to me that it is impossible to think of curved 3 manifolds in terms normal R^3 @K.defaoite

Comment: Don't think so, as long as the manifold is smooth. But if the manifold isn't smooth, curvature isn't exactly well defined.

Comment: Note that an embedded surface may not be the boundary of an open subset, take for example the Mobius band

Comment: Does the mobius surface even have an interior?

Comment: This was my point indeed! PS: the word "interior" can be misleading in the context of differential geometry.

Comment: @Aplateofmomos You should tag to whom you are saying that. If it were to me, I don't really understand the confusion: could you develop a bit?

Comment: I had misread what you read before, I understand now. Thanks @Didier

Comment: Since Euclidean three-space is flat, any open submanifold bounded by a surface is indeed flat. There do exist, however, Riemannian $3$-manifolds bounded by a surface in Euclidean three-space that are not flat. For example, we can map Euclidean space (non-isometrically) to the complement of a point in a $3$-sphere by stereographic projection; the flat $3$-manifolds above map to three manifolds of positive curvature. (_How_ positive depends on the radius of the $3$-sphere.)